# Установка фокуса на EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

В xml у `editText` есть эти 2 атрибута:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Пытался установить фокус с помощью такого кода:

```
synchronized (getContext()) {
    editText.requestFocus();
    ((InputMethodManager) cntxt.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .showSoftInput(editText, SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Не работает.

**UPD:**
Подробнее.
В Navigation Drawer-е нажимаю кнопку, он закрывается, дальше во фрагменте (вкладки) пытаюсь установить фокус.

Никакие задержки не помогли.
`editText.requestFocus()` возвращает `true`.

Добавил к `View`, на который хочу установить фокус, `OnFocusChangeListener`.
Сначала `hasFocus` равен `true`, а потом `false`.

Thread Dupm при `hasFocus==false`:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
  at ru.obrazcenter.Utils$1MyFocusListener.onFocusChange(MyUtils.java:19)
  at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:4836)
  at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:7641)
  at android.view.View.clearFocusInternal(View.java:4728)
  at android.view.View.unFocus(View.java:4762)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:822)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:822)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.unFocus(ViewGroup.java:822)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:624)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:630)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.requestChildFocus(ScrollView.java:1397)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestChildFocus(ViewGroup.java:630)
  at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4610)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.handleFocusGainInternal(ViewGroup.java:604)
  at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:6999)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6978)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2369)
  at android.widget.ScrollView.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ScrollView.java:1433)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2373)
  at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6945)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1296)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
  at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
  at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Comment: проверяли тут?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991522/how-can-i-set-the-focus-and-display-the-keyboard-on-my-edittext-programmatical

Comment: @upward, уже пробовал, не работает (

Comment: для чего вы используете synchronized ?

Comment: В какой момент вызываете `requestFocus()`? Возможно слишком рано при создании экрана?

Comment: И второй вопрос, на всякий случай, фокус не устанавливается или клавиатура не показывается?

Comment: @Соколов Я не помню в чем суть, но когда то была подобная проблема - по этому пишу в комментариях. У вас где то в это же классе используется requestFocus() и по каким то причинам реквест фокус начинает не корректно работать. Вообщем, попробуйте убрать дублирование реквест фокуса.

Comment: @upward, у меня приложение с вкладками, по нажатию одной кнопки я должен переместится на определенную вкладку и EditText должен получить фокус. Без синхронайзд валится ошибка, потому что EditText может быть не инициализирована в onCreate() фрагмента.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, 1) См. коммент выше. 2) Ни фокуса ни клавиатуры.

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, только в том же методе - switch с reqestFocus для разных вьюшек. Убрать не получится.

Comment: Похоже что кто-то перехватывает фокус

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением этой строки перед `requestFocus`:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Строку `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` в файле разметки android почему-то игнорирует.

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему вы не понимаете разницу между получением фокуса и показом клавиатуры. Они вообще то отличаются. Получение фокуса не означает показа клавиатуры, и обратно также верно - показ клавиатуры не означает наличия фокуса. Теоретически ведь устройство может иметь хардверную клавиатуру или иное устройство ввода, так что не надо путать фокус и показ виртуальной клавиатуры друг с другом.

Возвращаясь к сути вопроса, чтобы совместить получение фокуса и показ виртуальной клавиатуры используйте такой код:

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =  
           (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
  editText.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
        editText.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

По хорошему, этот способ надо совмещать с проверкой на наличие хардверной клавиатуры:

```
private boolean isHardwareKeyboardAvailable(Context context) { 
   return context.getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS; 
}
```

Comment: Гигант программирования

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вынести эту логику в метод статический и вынеси его в какой-нибудь класс Utils.

```
public class KeyboardUtil {
    public static void initFocusAndShowKeyboard(final EditText et, final Context context) {
    et.requestFocus();
    et.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Что-то на подобие такого и добавь задержку как в моем примере, это должно сработать (Давно боролся с этой проблемой - не помню в чем там суть, но точно какая то неприятная ерунда).

Comment: У меня не работает (((

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение в вопросе.

Comment: @Соколов что вообще вы пытаетесь сделать? Какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить этим?

Comment: у меня есть довольно большая форма на нескольких вкладках. При нажатии на кнопку программа пытается получить с EditText-ов и с CheckBox-ов данные, если пользователь что-то не так ввел или оставил поля пустыми, он видит список ошибок при нажатии на его пункт открывается вкладка и определенный элемент должен получить фокус.